# how to convert some lists into a data frame so that to create a xlsx file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**edit** this is the main txt that i exracted this output from :
**interface Port-channel2
switchport trunk allowed vlan 5,20,30,101,134,201,381
interface Port-channel1
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
switchport trunk allowed vlan 5,20,30,101,134,201,381
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
channel-group 1 mode on
interface GigabitEthernet1/0
switchport trunk allowed vlan 5,20,30,101,134,201,381
channel-group 2 mode on
interface GigabitEthernet1/1
switchport trunk allowed vlan 5,20,30,101,134,201,381
channel-group 2 mode on
interface GigabitEthernet1/2
interface GigabitEthernet1/3
ip route 172.16.1.203 255.255.255.255 GigabitEthernet0/1**
I have this output and I want to save it in xlxs fifth column :

```
('interface', '', 'trunk', '5,20,30,101,134,201,381')
('interface', '', 'trunk', '5,20,30,101,134,201,381')
('interface', '2', 'trunk', '5,20,30,101,134,201,381')
('interface', '2', 'trunk', '5,20,30,101,134,201,381')
```

and I want to make four columns of names `['interface', 'switch-port','trunk','Vlan']`

**The expected output**

```
interface | switch-port| trunk| Vlan|
interface  | ''        | Trunk | 5,20,30,101,134,201,381
interface  | ''        | Trunk | 5,20,30,101,134,201,381
interface  |  2        | Trunk | 5,20,30,101,134,201,381
interface  |   2       | Trunk | 5,20,30,101,134,201,381
```

Comment: What is the fifth column you mentioned?

Comment: Maybe try making a csv file first, which is easier.  This can then be converted into xlsx in several ways.

Comment: i have inserted the main txt that i extracted the output from if there will be another way to extract it as a dataframe directly

Answer (score 0):

If you can get your data into a list like below, you can use this to create your xlsx file

```
data=[('interface', '', 'trunk', '5,20,30,101,134,201,381'),
('interface', '', 'trunk', '5,20,30,101,134,201,381'),
('interface', '2', 'trunk', '5,20,30,101,134,201,381'),
('interface', '2', 'trunk', '5,20,30,101,134,201,381')]

df= pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['interface', 'switch-port','trunk','Vlan'])
df.to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: how can i reach to make the above output in this fourm?

Comment: i have inserted the main txt that i extracted the output from if there will be another way to extract it as a dataframe directly

Comment: It’s unclear where you get this data. From file? From a script?